# Jquery Doesn't function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have write this cause to show and hide select component with jQuery, but it doesn't function, can you tell me where is the problem?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:100,200,400">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700,400,300">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is CSS part to display.hide

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hide {
       display: none;
    }                  
</style>
```

The jQuery code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    function changeType() {
            if ($("#typeservice").val() == "voice") {
                $("#country").show();
                $("#sgnl").show();
                $("#Operator").hide();
                $("#tech").hide();
            }
            if ($("#typeservice").val() == "data") {
                $("#country").show();
                $("#sgnl").hide();
                $("#Operator").show();
                $("#tech").hide();
            }
            if ($("#typeservice").val() == "Radio") {
                $("#country").show();
                $("#sgnl").hide();
                $("#Operator").hide();
                $("#tech").show();
            }
    }
});
</script>   
</head>
<body> 
    <select id="typeservice" style="width: 100px" onchange="changeType();">
    </select>

    <select id="sgnl" style="width: 100px; ">
    </select>

    <select  id="country" style="width: 100px;">
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

But all the select component appears and no display or dynamic show!

Comment: There are no `<option>` items in your `<select>` tags so the `<select>` tags have nothing to show.

Comment: you added two different versions of jquery library in the same page first line and last line use any one.

Comment: don't you think there is something wrong in `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-   1.8.0.min.js`... there are extra space between `jquery-` and `1.8.0` so `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js`

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: i removed here the options beut i have them in my code,and i tried with one version and it doesn't work, sure that there are no other things to do ???????

Comment: `code.jquery.com/jquery-   1.8.0.min.js`, where is the problem?? It leaped out at me

Comment: i cheked the web console browser, and find this
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
dynamic.html:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defineddynamic.html:20 (anonymous function)
dynamic.html:53 Uncaught ReferenceError: changeType is not defineddynamic.html:53 onchange

Comment: Do you even read what we wrote? We gave you the solution three times already. You have SPACES in your script name inclusion, of course it can't work. So jQuery is not loaded, so `$` is not defined.

Comment: read the comment first include  the jquery source correctly. then try let me know is there again an error ?

Comment: trust me i have delated the space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In document ready function hide all select component other than typeservice dropdown. Try the following code to hide components in document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#country").hide();
    $("#sgnl").hide();
    $("#Operator").hide();
    $("#tech").hide();
});
```

Comment: You can use it `$("#country, #sgnl, #Operator, #tech").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an accepted answer here, this is only an another method.

We can bind the `onchange` event of a select dropdown list using jquery

**Note :** it is better to use if else rather than if here

**javascript**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$(document.body).on('change','#typeservice',function(){
     if ($("#typeservice").val()=="voice") {
    $("#country").show();
    $("#sgnl").show();
    $("#Operator").hide();
    $("#tech").hide();
     }
  else if ($("#typeservice").val()=="data") {
    $("#country").show();
    $("#sgnl").hide();
    $("#Operator").show();
    $("#tech").hide();
     }

   else if ($("#typeservice").val()=="Radio") {
    $("#country").show();
    $("#sgnl").hide();
    $("#Operator").hide();
    $("#tech").show();
      }

});
 });
```

**html**

```
 <select  id="typeservice" style="width: 100px">
    </select>

    <select id="sgnl" style="width: 100px; ">
     </select>

     <select  id="country" style="width: 100px;">
     </select>
```